# Search on multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

In my PowerBI App I have a visual tool called 'Text Filter' that provides a text search tool for finding data quickly for a single column of data in the table.  The problem is that I want it to
search on multiple text columns instead of just one.

I created a calculated column that combines all the text columns I want to search:

DAX

```
srch_data = [Item No] & "~" & [DocumentNo] & "~" & [OrderNo] & "~" & [Description] & "~" & related(Posted_AR_Header[External_Document_No_]) & "~" & RELATED(Posted_AR_Header[No]) & "~" & RELATED(Posted_AR_Header[ShiptoAddress]) & "~" & RELATED(Posted_AR_Header[ShiptoCity] )
```

Next, I applied the new calculated column (`srch_data`) to the `Text Filter` visual tool.

It all works fine but it seems like there should be a better way to highlight/filter row data that meets the search criteria for multiple columns in the table.

Is there a better way to search for text in multiple columns??

9/3 update - Apparently there is not a better way to do this...

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Search-on-multiple-columns/m-p/2054886#M768023

Comment: How do you imagine this better way? Show us 2 rows of sample data. What desired results you would like to achieve?

Comment: A search visual tool should have the ability to search multiple columns. It's a little loony that I have to use DAX with a calculated column to achieve this. I already got an answer to my question on community.powerbi.com and the way I'm doing is apparently the only way to do it.

Comment: I imagine the Text Filter tool could be a million times better if you could add more than one column..  I need to have a search tool like this because our customers call in with shipping label info and our people here need to be able to view/find an invoice using the shipping label info that is spread across multiple columns.  Without a calculated column to do this, I would have to have around 10 search widgets on my report page.

Answer (score 0):

After having a similar issue and searchign on multiple forums, I decided to create a hybrid solution that works well for me. Requirement was to be able to search over multiple fields but also have 'smart search' or 'auto fill' featured.
Smart Filter by OKViz is much more powerful than the Microsoft Text filter custom viz. This custom viz allows 'auto fill' but not searching over multiple columns.

The solution on every forum I read was to concatenate the columns into one field to create one long string. This wouldn't work with auto fill. Instead, I pivoted the columns I wanted to search on by the ID of the fact table to create another table, simply containing ID and search_values.

Creating the relationship between the new table and the fact table as a many-to-one relationship and cross-filtering in both directions got it to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).